# Is there any method to get package context in android studio ....?

Tags: java, android

```java
private void passcodeIntent(Context context, String pack) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, auth.class);
    pack = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(pack, auth.class);
    Toast.makeText(context, "long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    check = false;
}
```

My intent is not working. I created a separate method for the intent but `getApplicationContext` is not working.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `Intent`... so what does "not working" mean? Note that you do not need `getApplicationContext()` to create an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace
`Intent intent = new Intent(pack,auth.class);`

With

`Intent intent = new Intent(context,auth.class);`

Intent need Context there is no specific need of ApplicationContext